# google maps api - how to get location information /place_id from shareable links maps.goo.gl

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have several thousand maps.goo.gl shareable links I need to get the coordinates (lat/long) and/or place id so i can then use google maps api and load an embedded map on my page. I cannot open in browser to expand the link manually to grab info from the link as that would be impractical.

So is there any way via google maps api v3 to feed it the shared links to get the location information from it?

Tried googling for this but cannot seem to find any answers.